# why wild pointer holds zero address rather than garabge address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have been trying to find the size of an particular datatype like "int" without using sizeof() and found this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int *ptr;   /*Declare a pointer*/
    printf("Size of ptr = %d\n",ptr);
    ptr++;

    printf("Size of ptr = %d\n",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This returns correct size for int. How? 
Isn't wild pointer suppose to contain garbage address rather than zero. And if it contains zero how is it different than NULL pointer as NULL is (void*)0 ?

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, anything can happen. You should not have any particular expectation

Comment: `ptr` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value. Reading it is undefined behavior. You won't learn anything useful from this code.

Comment: How is garbage different from zero? That's essentially your question. Actually the C++ standard doesn't say that 'wild pointers' have 'garbage values'. It says that programs which read uninitialised variables have undefined behaviour. Which means that compilers can compile such programs in any way they like, and still be compliant with the C++ standard.

Comment: @M.M As I read the question, the OP tries to determine `sizeof int` by subtracting the pointer values after vs. before the increment. I believe this is technically UB, however it may still work as expected in most implementations. It is not all that different from the old macros for `offsetof` before it became part of the language.

Comment: Make `ptr` point to something relevant (eg `int i;ptr = &i;`) before using the pointer, it doesn't matter if `i` is not initialized.

Comment: On a 64-bit system, `sizeof(ptr)` will be `8`.  But the printf statement will likely only pop 4 bytes off for %d assuming sizeof(int) is 4.

Comment: @dxiv as you said i was trying to determine by subtracting pointer values after vs 
 before increment. But while doing this i was expecting UB but got correct result. I tried this in gcc and g++ both in linux and it gave me correct result. So that make me think how gcc g++ differentiate in NULL and WILD if both holds 0?

Comment: `NULL`  can be defined as `0` or `((void*)0)`, but that doesn't mean that a `NULL` pointer is zero. It means that when you assign zero to a pointer, it assigns `NULL` to it, whatever that is. (It is zero on many systems, but not all.)

Comment: @kpk The fact that your unassigned pointer had an initial value of `0` (which is the same as `NULL`) is purely accidental. The value may be different next time you run it, or if you compile it with the next version of the compiler. That said, `(int)((int*)ptr + 1) - (int)((int*)ptr) == sizeof int` *will* hold true regardless of the value of `ptr` in most implementations where a pointer "fits" into an int, and the UB part of it is of a more subtle variety.

Comment: `I was expecting UB but got correct result` UB includes correct results. Undefined means undefined.

Comment: @dxiv `offsetof` has always been in Standard C

Comment: @selbie on x64, printf will use registers for the first argument

Comment: @dxiv: *"is purely accidental."* Some compilers, in some configurations (debug) guaranty zero-initialization of uninitialized variables (which is IMO a wrong default value for debugging).

Comment: @M.M You're right about `offsetof`. I'll censor my pre-C89 memories more carefully ;-)

Comment: It is common behavior by (dumb) tools to set the stack to all-zeroes in debug build. For the sake of hiding bugs, I suppose. Then when you switch to release build, everything comes crashing down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ptr` is uninitialised, its value is indeterminate and accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.  The meaning of "undefined", somewhat ironically, is defined by C and C++ standards to mean something like "this standard doesn't constrain what happens".

Beginners often incorrectly assume this means it must contain a "garbage value" or be a "wild pointer"  or "add some colourful description here" but that is simply not the case.

The meaning of "value is indeterminate" or "the behaviour on accessing the value is undefined" is that any behaviour is permitted from code that accesses the value.

Accessing the value is necessary to print it, increment it, or (in case of a pointer) dereference it (access contents of the address identified by the pointer's value).

The behaviour of code that accesses the value is undefined.  Giving a printed value of zero, `42`, or a "garbage value" are all correct outcomes.     Equally, however, the result could mean no output, or undesirable actions, such as reformatting a hard drive.   The behaviour may even change over time if the code is executed repeatedly.   Or it may be 100% repeatable (for a specific compiler, specific operating system, specific hardware, etc).

Practically, it is quite common for code with undefined behaviour to give no sign of malfunction during program testing, but to later cause some nasty and visible but unintended effect when the program is installed and executed on a customer's computer.   That tends to result in grumpy customers, bug reports that the developers may be unable to replicate, and stress for developers in trying to fix the flaw.

Trying to explain why undefined behaviour results in some particular outcome (such as printing a value of zero) is therefore pointless.

Comment: Re “the meaning of "value is indeterminate" … is that any behaviour is permitted from code that accesses the value”: That is not correct in C. In C, using an indeterminate value (not “accessing”; accessing includes writing, and certainly an object with indeterminate value may be written to) produces some value, and that value may be different in each instance (for example, `printf("%d %d", x, x)` may produce “3 7”). (If the type has a trap representation, the value may be a trap representation, which results in undefined behavior, but that is a separate issue.)

Comment: Re “Trying to explain why undefined behaviour results in some particular outcome (such as printing a value of zero) is therefore pointless”: This is not correct. The fact that the C standard does not impose any requirements on behavior it says is “undefined” does not mean there are no other requirements or causal relationships. The behaviors of buggy programs often contain clues to the bugs, even if those behaviors are not defined by the C standard, and finding a bug by reasoning about the behavior is often much cheaper and faster than scouring the source code without guidance.

Comment: Furthermore, some behaviors that are not defined by the language standard are defined by compilers as extensions, and so of course they can be explained.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Feel free to post an answer to the question that you consider correctly addresses your points.

Answer (score -2):

the first print will have garbage or zero, depends on your compiler and previous value that was in the memory location.
If it was zero, then the second print will have the size of int, because incrementing a pointer increments with the size of the pointee.

for instance:

```
char *x = 0;
x++; //x=1

int *y = 0;
y++; //y=4
```

In your case, if you got a 0 on the first print, it was the same as if you initialized it to NULL, but **you can't count it to always be zero**.